# Using Bi-Directional USB-C Switch to switch between Ubuntu and Windows connected to dock -- layout issues with ubuntu

Tags: drivers, hardware, window, docking, kvm-switch

I am a rather new ubuntu user, but I use a bidirectional USB-C switch to link both my work computer (Windows) and my personal computer (running latest version of Ubuntu) connected to a docking station through which I have all my peripherals attached.

The trouble that I'm running into is that when I switch back from Windows to Ubuntu using the USB-C switch, all of my Ubuntu windows are all over the place and not at all how I left them. Some windows will be overlapping on other, whereas others might just be completely glitched.

I've looked into using a KVM switch but I can't seem to find a product that has quite what I want (USB-C computer connection) and multiple monitor support.

Does anyone have any advice regarding how to resolve the issue that I experience upon switching back to Ubuntu and my windows?

Comment: Seems like the dock switch automatically disconnects itself from whoever is not in use.

Comment: It's helpful if you're clear/specific with details; ie. rather than the *latest version of Ubuntu*, refer to say Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop for example. The 2023-October being the latest release, and Desktop meaning you're using the Desktop release (using GNOME Desktop/GUI) rather than Ubuntu 23.10 Server (no GUI/desktop).

Comment: @guiverc sorry im using Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64 and GNOME 44.3. Kernel version is 6.2.0-39-generic. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can remove my laptop display from linux somehow? I think the problem is that when i disconnect the dual-monitor, ubuntu reverts to using the single monitor on my laptop, which results in the scrambling when i reconnect

Comment: @mcendu --> im thinking that ubuntu is reverting back to my built-in display when i disconnect even when my laptop is closed. is there a way to totally disconnect the laptop display?

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus *unsupported* on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I suggest keeping your system offline; the 6.2 kernel is *unsupported* and thus *unpatched* for security issues via Ubuntu (its EOL), your release isn't the *latest* and is in fact EOL. Your system would have warned you to *release-upgrade* back in October (*unless you disabled warnings*) as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades